# The system says that I don't have any vote and I don't win the Vox Populi badge

Tags: support

Yesterday I cast all my votes, the system says that I can't vote, but I can't see my Vox Populli badge. The system yesterday stop my Vox Populli advance un 38 votes. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's how it works. You have 30 votes for questions and answers, plus 10 votes for questions; you get 40 votes only if you cast those 10 votes for questions before you cast 30 votes for answers.

In your case, you cast 8 votes for questions, and 30 votes for answers.

Comment: thanks, I never read this, I just read in the badge description "Use the maximum 40 votes in a day". Where we can found this information?

Comment: Answers about the exact criteria for badges can found on [StackExchange Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) questions. For example, here's a [question about Vox Populi](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117687/how-to-get-vox-populi-badge-when-you-can-no-longer-vote-after-32-votes).